# Combining two disjoint ddrescue backup images

Tags: hard-drive, debian, backup, external-hard-drive, ddrescue

I have a 3 TB drive which recently started to malfunction. I was using the ddrescue utility on Debian to read data off the disk to a different external hard drive. However, after 2 TB of data had been written to a single image file, the process terminated. This was because the hard drive to which I was writing is using the Ext2 filesystem, which has a filesize limit of 2 TB.

Below, I'll describe what I'm doing and what I plan on doing later. I would really appreciate it if someone could verify that I haven't horribly messed up and that what I plan on doing will work.

- I ran the ddrescue utility normally on the 3 TB broken hard drive (A), writing data to hdd.img on a functional 4 TB hard drive (B).
- B is using Ext2. Therefore, ddrescue stopped when hdd.img grew to be 2194719883264 bytes large.
- I checked the log file and noticed that the last line is "0x1FEFF7F0000  0xBBA1010000  ?", which indicates that every sector including and after 0x1FEFF7F0000 was not tried.
- Therefore, I started a new ddrescue process using the parameters "--input-position=2194719883264 --output-position=0", writing data to a file hdd_second_half.img on B.
- I plan on buying a new 4 TB hard drive (C). When C is here and ddrescue finishes writing to hdd_second_half.img, I will (1) copy hdd.img onto C and (2) append hdd_second_half.img to hdd.img with the command "hdd_second_half.img >> hdd.img".
- I will manually merge the log files for ddrescue corresponding to hdd.img and hdd_second_half.img and run ddrescue on the final, complete hdd.img file on C sufficiently many times to recover the data on all failed sectors.
- I will mount the image file and access my data.

In particular, it is the appending/concatenation step that worries me -- I am basically trying to work around the fact that I screwed up and forgot to verify that I was using a filesystem that could actually support a 3 TB file.